# PDE modeling (heat conduction and flow)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, applications

The heat conduction is expressed by a classic heat equation like

$p(x) u_t + div (A(x) u) = f(x,t) $.

If I look at a porous medium like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Cam_Bioceramics_Large_Porous_Granule.gif) (solid+gas) the heat equation should apply too (in a related form).

But what if there's a gas M in the open space of the medium and now there is another gas N flowing into the same space?
Can the heat conduction still be expressed in a single equation? Or does this require a system of equations?

How would such an equation or system of equations look like?

Comment: This is only an idea: Personally, I'm a researcher to two-phase flow equations. To describe the flow of two gases one uses the so called two-phase flow model. This models both phases seperately. (You could also take the Richards equation into account). Having such a solution, your porous medium could be interpreted as a solid but the parameters $p$ and $A$ depend on time, in virtue of the flow of the two gas-phases (of course the heat-conductivity might also depend on the density/saturation of the gases). Remark: The two-phase system looks alot like two coupled heat equations.